# How to print descriptive statistics on sentiment analyses using Python's TextBlob?

Tags: python, analytics, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am conducting a sentiment analysis for research purposes using TextBlob in Python 3. 
I used this code to retrieve the sentiment per line of feedback (around 4000 lines):

```
# Handle the file and import the textblob package for sentiment analysis
bestand = open("kolom_o_english.txt")
from textblob import TextBlob
from statistics import mean

# Create a "for" loop in which you first strip the lines and then print the analyses per line
for line in bestand:
    feedback = line.rstrip()
    blob1 = TextBlob(feedback)
    sentiment_score = blob1.sentiment
    print(feedback)
    print(sentiment_score)
```

Some examples of my output:

```
Nice
Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=1.0)
Mediocre
Sentiment(polarity=-0.5, subjectivity=1.0)
I have already retired and I think the questions are much more about people who are still working. It's good that this research is being done.
Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.55)
as a pensioner not that interesting for me
Sentiment(polarity=0.5, subjectivity=0.5)
Not really suitable for people who are already retired.
Sentiment(polarity=-0.275, subjectivity=0.75)
fine
Sentiment(polarity=0.4166666666666667, subjectivity=0.5)
```

Even though I can now analyze the sentiment of every line, what methods exist to make sense out of the data as a whole (e.g. mean, distribution etc.) and what lines of codes can I use for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you could analyze how the distribution in your data looks like - which words are more common for positive sentiment and which for negative. Depending on your dataset you could also investigate how, for instance, the sentiment in different comments about a product looks like.

Comment: You could then even draw some diagrams to see get a better view on your data (libraries such as seaborn(https://seaborn.pydata.org/) can do the job. And, of course, you can make use of the pandas package (https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: @t_e_o Thanks for the tips! Do you have any idea how I extract the polarity scores from each line and put them in a list to do analyses?

Comment: you can take the text from each line and then do TextBlob(lineText).sentiment  as shown here: https://planspace.org/20150607-textblob_sentiment/